# Here Maps Blank Squares Unauthorized

Tags: passwords, here-maps-rest, heremaps

When loading hear maps on our site some of the squares are blank and then looking at the url for the square the following is returned

error: Unauthorized
error_description: This is not a valid app_id and app_code pair. Please verify that the values are not swapped between the app_id and app_code and the values provisioned by HERE (either by your customer representative or via http://developer.here.com/myapps) were copied correctly into the request.

The other squares load so the key is working, anyone know why this is happening?